# PS2 mouse stopped working after update

Tags: keyboard, mouse

**Ubuntu 20.04.1** installed in my back up computer back in Sept. Worked fine over several tests, and uses including a few days ago. But yesterday, after a Ubuntu software upgrade, the screen just went black. Stayed black. No amount of keyboard key combinations, mouse movement or yelling at the black monitor made it come back. So did a hard reset. This system is 6 yo ASUS AMD Quad Core 64-bit. Standard setup, using the built-in video chip.

That reset behaved strangely, going to a repair screen. Eventually, I took a guess that there was a hardware issue, and guessed again that it might be the PS2 mouse driver. So pulled that mouse and plugged in a USB wireless mouse. That allowed the computer to boot, but it double pumps, every time. It cycles through, gets to the Gurb menu then reboots. IT DID NOT DO THIS BEFORE that upgrade. On the 2nd pass, it gets to the Gurb screen that allows me to choose Ubuntu 20.04 or Win10 and eventually boots.

So that's where it is now. It's usable with a USB mouse. I WANT TO BE ABLE TO USE THE PS2 MOUSE. But can't find any updated method to restore operation in 20.04.

And I'd like a way to fix the double boot sequence.

Anyone know how to restore the PS2 operation? THANKS!

PS I found this page...but have no idea what I'm suppose to do to restore operation...https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man4/psm.4freebsd.html

Comment: Is it a ps/2 mouse plugged into a ps/2 port or usb via an adapter?  Have you tried using a usb adapter?

Comment: @xiota: It is (was) plugged into a PS2 port. I cannot find my PS2 to USB adapter so I can't test that. Keep in mind that the PS2 mouse has worked fine for a couple months now. The upgrade trashed it. It's like there's no 20.04 recognition of  PS2 hardware now.

Comment: I don't have any computers with ps/2 port anymore.  Try checking the psmouse module.  Maybe it isn't loading or got blacklisted or something.  Maybe also try a live cd to see if it works there.  If it does, then there's definitely some sort of config issue.

Comment: @xiota: PSMouse module? I haven't loaded a PS2 mouse module (assume you mean the software, not the hardware module) for 20 odd years. Don't know where to find one. Can you link? Google isn't much help. I'll give the live CD a shot right now.

Comment: @xiota: PS2 mouse works fine with the Live CD of 20.04.1. Rebooting gives this error message after almost 4 minutes of a black screen: AHCI Controller Unavailable. Then goes into a boot loop. Restarting with a USB mouse works fine. PS2 mouse works fine on my other ASUS mobo running 20.04.1 except it hasn't had any recent upgrades.

Comment: @xiota: I used the wrong term above, rebooting with a USB mouse STILL is giving a double pump, it loops through twice before stopping at the Grub page then booting to the splash page. That's the 2nd thing wrong with this last update served by Ubuntu. Also probably hardware related I'm just hoping solving the PS2 mouse issue also fixes the dbl boot loop.

Comment: I was referring to the psmouse kernel module.  Run `lsmod | grep psmouse` to see if it's loaded. According to [Ubuntu will not install with AHCI mode enabled in Bios](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/ubuntu-will-not-install-with-ahci-mode-enabled-in-bios-sata-iii-hard-drive-4175473528/), AHCI unavailable may be related to another kernel module.

Comment: It won't boot with the PS2 mouse so when I test lsmod with my USB mouse it returns null to grep psmouse. Also, I found my PS2 to USB adapter and what happens with that is that ASUS BIOS won't go past it's splash screen. After 5 minutes, I gave up and pulled the adapter, and then it booted. So not usable with this computer. And finally, I did have an ASMedia USB expansion card installed and removing that helps reduce the number of boot loops.

Comment: Try `sudo grep -Ril psmouse /etc` to find files that might refer to psmouse.  Examine them in a text editor to see what they're doing.  If there are no references to psmouse, you can try to force load it... add a line that says `psmouse` to `/etc/modules` *and* `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`.  Then run `sudo update-initramfs -ck all`.

Comment: O_o, cool. I like those kinds of fixes. But, sadly, I bumped the computer last night and it went all wacky doodle on me and won't boot. I'm gunna try to fix it this morning. I'm better able to sit at my main computer (this one) now for extended periods so at least I have one working I'm able to use. (It's a medical thing, no biggie). I'm using the PS2 mouse too. I will see if the next auto upgrade trashes this hardware setup maybe. Or not, it was touch and go with the other computer so I might quickly switch to the USB mouse. Still, I want to be able to use the PS2 mouse.

Comment: I wonder if the other computer has failing hardware.  I had unusual problems with a computer several years ago... and it turned out the motherboard was failing.

Comment: Just this moment got it up and running. I have fixed hundreds of computers over the years and this one is not exhibiting the type of hardware issues I'm used to finding. In addition it's my back up computer, the one I use for testing drives or other equipment my friends might be having trouble with and it maybe has 50 hours run time on it. To restore operation today, all I did was reset the BIOS jumper and it was up and running. Whatever I did with bumping the keyboard last night somehow upset the BIOS. Anyway, back to normal.

Comment: If I could talk directly with the Ubuntu developers (if this turns out to be a change on their part), I'd remind them that there are 10's of millions of PS2 keyboards and PS2 mice out there in computer land. And they are much loved for a simple reason...the connectors aren't big and horky like the USB connector. And the mini USB connectors are too small for us older people, though they have their place on Androids for sure. It's really a superior connector for an full sized office computer compared to the USB.

Comment: My computer still loads the psmouse module.  I don't even have a ps/2 port.  Don't know why yours doesn't load it.  Let me know if the steps I outlined earlier help.

Comment: This: sudo grep -Ril psmouse /etc --Returns No Such File in 10 or so cases.

Comment: Also...remember when I said I reset the BIOS? So I thought I'd try to boot with the PS2 mouse...got to Grub, pressed enter on the Ubuntu choice and it went to a burgendy page with nothing on it, BUT THE MOUSE WORKED. Then it went to a burgundy page with 20.04 ... on it, mouse stopped working. THEN Ubuntu TURNED OFF MY CPU!!! The fan stopped running, all the lights were lit, but the video went away. No kybd lights...couldn't do anything except shut off the PSU, change the mouse back to USB and reboot. Cool huh?

Comment: 2 days later, I'm feeling much healthier and I've returned to my primary computer. And I soon get a notification of an upgrade waiting. I DON'T FEEL COMFORTABLE INSTALLING IT. Any upgrade that shuts down the CPU but doesn't do a reboot or a total shutdown is just too weird and a huge black mark on the writers. That's one of the biggest failures in the history of home computers. It's just not done. I don't want to under sell how important it is that something like that NEVER happens. Do you have a suggestion or a test? PS I'm still using the PS2 mouse on this computer.

Comment: "Any upgrade that shuts down the CPU but doesn't do a reboot or a total shutdown is just too weird and a huge black mark on the writers." – Not sure what you're referring to.  No one is stopping you from rebooting.  It's possible to create a snapshot using hard links.  You can ask as another question.

Comment: I didn't express myself clearly. Not taking about any person at all but about the upgrade which seems to have a pathway for bad actors to exploit if they have the skill. And that is to shut down the CPU, which basically locks up the computer BUT it seems to be running as all the fans except the CPU fan are running. As a retired computer consultant, seems to me that this can lead to all sorts of mis-identified issues and expenses by an infected owner if this were exploited as a virus. Perhaps I'm overstating the exploit, I'll leave that for the experts to decide.

Comment: Are you referring to kernel live patching?  I'm pretty sure an opt-in process is required to use it.

Comment: Sorry took so long to comment on your question. I'm now down in Pahrump, NV after a miserable travel experience in my RV due to the cold. And I'm a bit more settled and healthy. Anyway, NO, it was not live patching that I know of UNLESS that is what the built in Software Upgrade Auto install does after it asks permission. I have one upgrade now waiting in the wings on this Ubunut 20.04 computer too, I haven't installed it yet, AND I'm using the PS2 mouse right now. I'm hoping for a resolution or a retraction or notification of a fix for this before I proceed with installing the upgrade.

Comment: I filed a bug report about this over a week ago and haven't heard back. Not sure they'll say anything to me about it. I labeled it a security risk. Do you have any fixes in mind?

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED INFO**: I did submit a bug report back on Dec. 7th, 2020 and never heard back. What I did was go out and buy a USB keybord and a couple USB mice and that got me by. I could not find an ergonomic keyboard I wanted at that time! Both of my ergonomic keyboards are PS2 and using a PS2 to USB adapter never worked. I did test a few times in January and February and finally gave up on the PS2 connector that came with my motherboards, figuring it wouldn't ever work again with Ubuntu 20.04.

Then today, May 12, 2021; decided to test it one last time before tossing my PS2 keyboards and mice and HEY! my favorite keyboard works now!!

Took them I don't know how long but eventually the bug report worked I guess and Ubuntu 20.04.2 again recognizes and works with PS2 hardware. YEA!!